# How to create that table?

Tags: tables, cell

I used a code, I have a table which created by using `tabularx`, but the problem is that, I want to create that following table by using `tabularx` and using `textwidth`, where the value of the first column A is `0.1/5`, the column TexttExText is `0.2/5` and TextTextText is `0.2/5`.

I wanna need an information, I want that the column accept the auto break line because I will remplace `T`
by a long text.

The picture of the table [image]

I tried to create that following code, please help me :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % new
\usepackage{enumitem}                               % new
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, 
                  after=\end{minipage}                   
                  }


\begin{table} [htp]
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
  \begin{table} [htp]
    \setcellgapes{4pt}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
{| L L| 
p{0.18\textwidth} |
p{0.18\textwidth} | 
}  
  \hline
  
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \multirow{2}{=} {\centering A}}  & 
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering TextTextText} &  
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering TextTextText}           
            
              \\ 
    \hline
    
    
      \hline
  
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ {\centering MADM}}  & 
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering T} &  
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering T}           
            
              \\ 
    \hline
    
    

    
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
```

Comment: Must  your table fit on a single column or be text wide? Does it have three or four columns?

Comment: I wanna use a single column ... 5/10

Comment: And the number of columns in the table?

Comment: What's the difference to your previous question [How to use multirow in multicolumn to merge a tabularx cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550495/134144)? The image of the desired output as well as the provided code seem to be pretty identical, at least from a first glance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multirow in multicolumn to merge a tabularx cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550495/how-to-use-multirow-in-multicolumn-to-merge-a-tabularx-cell)

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%{svjour3}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % new

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

 \begin{table} [htp]
    \setcellgapes{4pt}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\hsize =0.66\hsize}L| >{\hsize =0.66\hsize}L|
 >{\hsize =1.34\hsize}L|>{\hsize =1.34\hsize}L|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \multirowcell{1}{\centering A}} &
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering TexttEXTtext} &
   \multirow{2}{=} {\centering TextTextText} \\
    \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ {\centering MADM}} &
 T & T \\
 \hline
 AAAA & AAA & T & T \\
 \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I cant remove the space between the first and the second table

Comment: Error "! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \usepackage"

Comment: Compiling this very code, and only this code??

Comment: What are your first and second tables?

Comment: I cant remove the space between the first and the second table

Comment: The space between the head and the first column

Comment: Do you mean it should be as in my updated answer? You had written two consecutive  `\hline`s in your code, and I thought it was purposely.